What is wrong with this bash script (I suspect an issue withspaces and dashes in filenames and quoting)
I'm banging my head on what should be an easy one-off task, and I just can't see what I am missing.
I have the following script:
#! /bin/bash

SRCDIR=/var/www/virtual/site.name/large-videos

find $SRCDIR -iname "*.mp4" | while read SRC
do
        DST=$( echo "$SRC" | cut -f6 -d"/" )
        DST=${SRC::-4}
        ffmpeg -i "$SRC" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -crf 28 "./$DST-small.mp4"
done

I note there are spaces and dashes in the filenames and I suspect the problem may be here, but I'm not certain, and can't see why this is the problem.
When I run this script I get the normal ffmpeg compression information, but then in red something that looks like
  tual/yournetmum.com/large-videos/FINANCE - Big Hat No Cattle.mp4: No such file or directory

(The above is not truncated, the line starts "tual" above, although the actual starting point of the truncation varies and is often mid-word - so this could be ffmpeg truncating the input - but that seems weird.)
How can I fix this script?

This, this and this; and this and this; possibly more.

It seems there were a number of errors - although not the ones I was expecting.  A comment on a post linked to by @KamilMaciorowski comment talked about the command "shellcheck" which I had not come across and it looks like this - in conjunction with other tweeks fixed the issue.
The main issues were that I needed to pass --nostdin to ffmpeg and possibly that I forgot to enquote SRC in the first DST= line initially.    There was also a stupid error on the second DST= line where I refered to SRC rather then DST
